# Could Web server and Application server be developed separately?

Tags: django, web

My friend has developed a recommend system in C++, now we want to make a web information system based on his work. As we both do not have no Web technology knowledge, I have some questions:

1. If we want to develop a web site which based on this recommend system, we should implement the recommend system in the application server and make a web server that could return the pages, right?
2. Then what web server we should use or use what technique to develop a web server to call the function in the recommend system? How the web server communicates with the application server?
3. Some web frameworks, such as Django, does it act as web server or application server or it is both?

As we have so much basic questions, do you have some books or website to recommend?

Answer (score 0):

You can think of your C++ app as a service that your Django app can execute to return values to your users. You could easily execute any application on the same server as Django and capture the response or you could create a thin HTTP API and put your C++ app on its own server and call it by HTTP from your Django app to make requests for your users.

https://www.djangoproject.com/ is a great place to start.